# Google Cloud VideoIntelligence - Is there a way to only call AnnotateVideo for a particular section of a video?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, video-intelligence-api

Currently I am using the AnnotateVideo function to analyse videos. Is there any way to analyse only a section of a video, such as providing start_time and end_time as an argument to the function ?

```
gs_video_path ='gs://'+bucket_name+'/'+videodata.video.path+videodata.video.name
print(gs_video_path)

video_client = videointelligence.VideoIntelligenceServiceClient()
features = [videointelligence.enums.Feature.OBJECT_TRACKING]
operation = video_client.annotate_video(gs_video_path, features=features)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can analyse only the sections you're interested in by providing a `VideoContext` with a `VideoSegment` list. Here is an example with a single 21..42s segment:

```
from google.cloud import videointelligence
from google.cloud.videointelligence import enums, types

video_client = videointelligence.VideoIntelligenceServiceClient()

gs_video_path = f'gs://{bucket_name}/{videodata.video.path}{videodata.video.name}'
features = [enums.Feature.OBJECT_TRACKING]
segment = types.VideoSegment()
segment.start_time_offset.FromSeconds(21)
segment.end_time_offset.FromSeconds(42)
context = types.VideoContext(segments=[segment])

operation = video_client.annotate_video(
    gs_video_path,
    features=features,
    video_context=context)
```

If you want more examples, I recently wrote this tutorial: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-video-intelligence-python3

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to analyse the full video and then retrieve the annotations for the specified times or frames, see this [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/video/cloud-client/analyze/analyze.py).

If this doesn't fit your requirements because the videos are too long and you want to process only a specific part, I suggest you to use an external tool to cut the video locally and then perform the annotation of that fragment. For example you can use the following code to cut the video (there are many others).

```
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip
ffmpeg_extract_subclip("video1.mp4", start_time, end_time, targetname="test.mp4")
```

And then you will have to process the video [from a local file](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/object-tracking#request_object_tracking_for_video_from_a_local_file)